# subgroup of a finitely generated group not necessarily finitely generated (Hungerford exercise)

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I found a relation that $ab=b^2a$. However, I have no idea how to show that $H$ is not finitely generated. I keep encountering some kind of a word problem. Could anyone please help me?